# fsck.ext4 unable to resolve UUID

Tags: linux, centos, iscsi, scientific-linux

While connecting remote iscsi storage I was getting above error.

This is the configuration of my iscsi server(target)

cat /etc/tgt/targets.conf

[image]

`tgtd` service is running in server side.

My client (initiator) configuration

First I tried this command

iscsiadm -m discoverdb -t st -p serverip -D

in client side it showing the target

`fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes
67 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1009 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 4154 * 512 = 2126848 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0de5df58
```

After that I created a partition using that target and created filesystem also

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1009     2095662    5  Extended
/dev/sda5               1         506     1050900   83  Linux
```

I mounted using UUID in /etc/fstab using this option

```
UUID=751c022c-f670-46a8-940c-317c60eb65b8 /data ext4    _netdev         0 0
```

In client side iscsi service is running

```
[root@client ~]# chkconfig --list | grep iscsi
iscsi           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iscsid          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

This is the UUID of /dev/sda5

```
[root@client ~]# blkid | grep /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5: UUID="751c022c-f670-46a8-940c-317c60eb65b8" TYPE="ext4"
```

While rebooting client it's taking 3-4 minute to boot, and it's getting stuck in iscsi service and after 3-4 minute later it's showing this error

[image]

If I manually mount the target uisng this command its working

```
[root@client ~]# iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2014-01.com.example:server.target1 -p 192.168.122.177 -l
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2014-01.com.example:server.target1, portal: 192.168.122.177,3260] (multiple)
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2014-01.com.example:server.target1, portal: 192.168.122.177,3260] successful.
```

```
[root@client ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda2             6.9G  3.2G  3.4G  49% /
tmpfs                 372M  228K  372M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1             194M   29M  156M  16% /boot
/dev/sda5            1011M   34M  926M   4% /data
```

How to solve this error and delay problem ?

**Update**

This is from /var/log/boot.log message

```
Starting iscsi: iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2014-01.com.example:server.target1, portal: 192.168.122.177,3260].
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
```

Comment: Umm, why would you post _images_ of simple text files? Much more work and it makes it impossible for us to copy/paste so we can't try out your setup without manually writing things out. Anyway, does it work better if you use `/dev/sda5` instead of the UUID?

Comment: @terdon If I use /dev/sda5 also it's not working. Ok I will update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client Side**

Just Specify Initiator Name in this file `/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi`

```
InitiatorName=iqn.2014-01.com.example:server.target1
```

Then it will work.